# Azure terraform storage account permission

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to learn more about azure open vpn configurations and how it work. So looking around I found a open source project on GitHub, at the following link:

https://github.com/terraform-azurerm-examples/example-hub.git (Thank you for your code)

I set all the variable I wanted, and removed the version from azure provider.

but when I run terraform apply, I got an error on azure Storage account.

the error is this one:

```
Error: reading queue properties for AzureRM Storage Account "examplehubw6sr1wyncn": queues.Client#GetServiceProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationPermissionMismatch" Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.\nRequestId:cce5a313-b003-005c-2bb2-9d8a2f000000\nTime:2021-08-30T15:19:07.9036073Z"
```

As far as I understand, the error is due to setting secret permissions, which I did updated giving `Get`, `List` and `Set` but the error keeps showing up.

I am using terraform version 0.14.5
and my azurerm version is 2.74.0

I never had this type of error, on my subscription I have administrator role.

Did anyone get this error and know how to solve it, I would really appreciate you help

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because your user does not have data plane permissions on your storage account - which is where Terraform wants to put the statefile. Give your user `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did add the role to my user but still getting the same error